programatically display tooltip on ngx-pie-chart
I have created a custom legend for my ngx pie charts. When you hover over an area of the pie, a tool-tip appears showing the value of that slice. I'd like to be able to also hover over the name in my legend and also have that same tool-tip appear over the pie. I can't seem to find anything in the DOM that would let me know which name is attached to which slice. Am I over-thinking this? Is there any easier way?

example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pie-chart-yabzrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

minimal reproducible code please, if possible a stackblitz!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pie-chart-yabzrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
